# How do i access a combobox text in a usercontrol from the wpf forms viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl with 4 combobox bound to collections in viewmodel for that usercontrol.

I have used this control in a wpf form. This wpf form has its own viewmodel.

How do i access the text from the 4 comboboxes within the wpf form's viewmodel?

Comment: please dont use wpf form! its wpf window/usercontrol/view ;)

Comment: would also be nice to see some code. setting datacontext for your wpf window, viewmodel code, xaml for your combobox and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: i saw that you have different viewmodels. now it depends of the use of your usercontrol and the use of mvvm:)

- you can use messenger or eventaggregator to comunicate the seleteditems from usercontrolviewmodel to mainviewmodel.
- you can also use RelativeSource binding in your usercontrol to bind the selecteditem to your mainviewmodel directly (usercontrol then is just a composition of controls).
- you can can rid of the usercontrol viewmodel and put all in the mainviewmodel and take my old example
- you can create DependencyProperties for the SelectedItems in your usercontrol!(not usercontrol viewmodel!) and bind these to the properties in your mainviewmodel. i think thats the cleanest way if the usercontrol should be a real usercontrol.

old example:
in your viewmodel: //the real code should of course implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise it properly

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> MyFirstCollection {get; set;}//init once, add,remove,clear to alter

 public string MySelectedCombobox1Value {get;set;}
```

in your usercontrol:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{MyFirstCollection }" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedCombobox1Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

thats all relating to your question. be sure that you set the `DataContext` right. you can check this with tools like snoop. the code i posted expected that the dataconext for the combobox is the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

The UserControl should inherit the data context of the form you're adding it to which would be the view model. Any bindings in the UserControl would then be relative to the inherited data context. Have you tried binding to a view model property to `ComboBox.Text`?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, misread your question. Didn't see that the user control already has its own view model.

While it seems like there's a better approach, you could expose dependency properties on the user control that exposé the text of each combobox. Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

The only clean way to do this is with binding, and the only way that would be recommended is if the user control exposes a `DependencyProperty` for the ViewModel or the individual text properties (as was suggested by sellmeadog) for consumption. Then you can have a property in the parent ViewModel that binds directly to that Dependency Property.